# MongoDB MapReduce (PHP) - Get unique keys of matched documents

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a PHP web application which uses a large MongoDB collection. Each Mongo document has a `_type` field, which can either be `red`, `green`, or `blue`. I have criteria supplied by the user: `groupName = "paint"` - I need to return a list of all the keys associated with documents where `groupName = "paint"`. This is my query that does just that:

```
$map = new MongoCode('
    function(){
        var keys = [];
        Object.keys(this).forEach(function(k){
            if(k != "_id" && k != "_type"){
                keys.push(k);
            }
        })
        emit(this.type,{"keys":keys});
    }
');

$reduce = new MongoCode('
    function(key,values){
        var uniqueKeys = {};
        var result = [];
        values.forEach(function(value){
            value.keys.forEach(function(k){
                if(!uniqueKeys[k]){
                     uniqueKeys[k] = 1;
                     result.push(k);
                 }
            })
        })
        return {"keys":result};
    }
');

$keyName = "groupName";
$keyValue = "paint";    

$commandOutput = $db->command(array(
   'mapreduce' => 'searchCollection', // collection name
   'map' => $map,
   'reduce' => $reduce,
   'query' => array($keyName => $keyValue),
   "out" => 'groupNameKeysCollection' // outputting to a collection
));
```

That works very nicely, but I need to know the value of `_type` for each key that gets spit out. How can I tack that on to each of the keys returned?

Comment: I am surprised this works inline to your application on a "large" collection. The amazement aside, before the MR is actually looked at have you tried completing this with the aggregation framework first? That is more designed for this kind of stuff

Comment: Oh is it? I'll have to give the aggregation framework a try - I'm pretty unfamiliar with the advanced MongoDB stuff... If anyone has an example of something like this I'd be happy to see it. I was surprised that I couldn't find an example somewhere in the docs...